# WSL2: Stuck on Downloading Visual Studio when using code . command after installing VSCODE under windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

**Hi after entering the following command in windows powershell in admin mode:**

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8000 connectaddress=192.168.224.1
```

**and typing `code . in WSL2`, the download gets stuck can you please write a straight forward resolution for this issue?.**

```
ALG_LIN code .
Updating VS Code Server to version 6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b)
Downloading: 100%
Failed
--2022-12-02 20:31:55--  https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b/server-linux-x64/stable
Connecting to 192.168.224.1:8000... connected.
Failed reading proxy response: Success
Retrying.
```

Answer (score -1):

> https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b/server-linux-x64/stable

The download link given in your output refers to the vscode installation package of linux.

Why not try to open [the official website](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and install vscode directly?

Comment: I downloaded VSCODE directly for windows on windows, code . is supposed to launch it from wsl2 directly then.

Comment: Can you manually install the latest version of vscode? Your output seems to be an error in the update process, not a problem with WSL2. I think if you run `code` command in cmd directly, you will get the same output

Comment: I want code to work in WSL2, not sure your anwer is pertinent.

Comment: @Ludogiraud `code` mentioned in my comment is the command in cmd.

Comment: Everything works on windows, it's in the UBUNTU WSL2 terminal that code . doesn't work.

Comment: Does the problem still exist after reinstalling the latest version of vscode?